# Checkout a lost commit on GitHub, that is on no branch

Tags: git, github

On GitHub I deleted a repository, from which I already created a Pull Request to another fork.

Now I can stil see the changes suggested in that PR  and I can browse the structure on that tree, but I cannot check out that lost branch:

https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/gluon/pull/1162/files

I can click on "View" to see this detached tree: https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/gluon/tree/7425d54a0b

How can I fork that tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

This describes how to checkout a pull request locally and subsequently create a branch from it.

https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

```
git fetch origin pull/1162/head:rkelevra
git checkout rkelevra
```